# Find with predicate starting at index

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, lodash

What is the best way to find an array item (not necessarily the index, but that works) that matches a predicate (so I cannot compare directly the items, forget `indexOf`) *starting from* an index.

I want to get the "next matching" item from an array, starting at the current position.

Below is my current implementation:

```js
var currentIndex = 1;

var results = [
  {status: 'AWAITING_APPROVAL'}, // Not matched
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
  {status: 'AWAITING_APPROVAL'},
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
];

var nextIndex = results
  .slice(currentIndex)
  .findIndex(function (content) {
    return content.status === 'AWAITING_APPROVAL';
  });

if (nextIndex !== -1) {
  nextIndex += currentIndex;
  // Here we can use nextIndex which is 4
  console.log(nextIndex);
}
```

Of course I could just do a basic for loop / ifs but I'm wondering if there is a better way (maybe using lodash).

Comment: What's wrong with your approach? Just replace `.findIndex()` with `.find()` to make it a little bit easier.

Comment: @Andreas the splice copies the array, not ideal. I'm looking at Nina's answer below that seems to do what I want

Comment: The third parameter to lodash's findIndex is the index to search from

Comment: @GruffBunny Yes! I missed this as it is not the case in lodash 3.x but that's useful for the next people landing here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a check for a greater index.

```js
var currentIndex = 1,
    results = [{ status: 'AWAITING_APPROVAL'}, { status: 'APPROVED'}, { status: 'APPROVED'}, { status: 'APPROVED'}, { status: 'AWAITING_APPROVAL'}, { status: 'APPROVED'}],
    nextIndex = results.findIndex(({ status }, i) => i > currentIndex && status === 'AWAITING_APPROVAL');

console.log(nextIndex);
```

Comment: I like this one, it trades the slice copy for a few more iterations and checks. Why not!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is the naïve for/if version

```js
var currentIndex = 1;

var results = [
  {status: 'AWAITING_APPROVAL'}, // Not matched
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
  {status: 'AWAITING_APPROVAL'},
  {status: 'APPROVED'},
];

var nextIndex;
for (nextIndex = currentIndex; nextIndex <= results.length; nextIndex++) {
  if (nextIndex === results.length) {
    nextIndex = -1;
    break;
  }
  if (results[nextIndex].status === 'AWAITING_APPROVAL') {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(nextIndex);
```